# jQuery ajax not working with JS confirmation modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

When a user clicks on ***Delete this post*** a modal pops up asking if the user is sure.

If OK, the AJAX proceeds as normal. But if the user clicks on Cancel, the delete action is happening as well.

I've tried `return false` in several parts of this AJAX code but it completely blocks the AJAX request.

I'd like to accomplish the correct behavior without using additional plugins (ie, dialog) -- anyone have suggestions? Thanks!

AJAX

```
$('.posts_delete').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var last_seg = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
            var link = 'chat/posts_delete/' + last_seg;

    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        dataType: "html",
        beforeSend: function(){
              confirmDeletePost();
//        return false;

            },          
        success: function() {
            $('#chat_thread').load('chat/posts_ajax/<?php echo $page_id; ?>');
            $('#posts_form input').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

JS

```
function confirmDeletePost() {
    return confirm("This post will be removed and you can't undo this action. Are you sure you want to delete?");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the result of the `confirm` — return `false` if the user cancels.

It would be simpler to use an `if` to only send the request if the user clicks OK in the first place.

Comment: @SLack and @Tadeck - how would the `return false` code look like? I've tested @Tadeck's solution and it works

Comment: @torr: `return cofirmDeletePost()`

Answer (score 3):

check this http://jsfiddle.net/jansian/wupmq/

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: thanks @Ian, works well too - i think I'll use @slaks for simplicity's sake

Comment: :) sure anytime, pleasure to help you

Answer (score 1):

This should work (attention! not tested):

```
$('.posts_delete').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if (confirm("This post will be removed and you can't undo this action. Are you sure you want to delete?")){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var last_seg = id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
        var link = 'chat/posts_delete/' + last_seg;

        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: function(){
                  confirmDeletePost();
    //        return false;

                },          
            success: function() {
                $('#chat_thread').load('chat/posts_ajax/<?php echo $page_id; ?>');
                $('#posts_form input').val('');
            }
        });
    }
});
```